# Non zero exit code in java , while submitting on codechef, otherwise works fine

Tags: java

For this code, on codechef to perform different operations as per query
I get non zero exit code, but it works fine on my machine. Is it a space problem or something else? I am using `StringTokenizer` for fast input, in the `FastScanner` class.

```
FastScanner sc = new FastScanner();
int n = sc.nextInt();
int q = sc.nextInt();
BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[n];
String val, s;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = new BigInteger("0");
}
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("1000000007");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s = sc.nextToken();
    arr[i] = new BigInteger(s);
}

while (q > 0) {
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    int st = sc.nextInt();
    int en = sc.nextInt();
    switch (c) {
        case 1: {
            val = sc.nextToken();
            BigInteger v = new BigInteger(val);

            for (int j = st - 1; j <= en - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j].add(v);
                arr[j] = arr[j].mod(m);
            }
            break;

        }
        case 2: {
            val = sc.nextToken();
            BigInteger v = new BigInteger(val);
            for (int j = st - 1; j <= en - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j].multiply(v);
                arr[j] = arr[j].mod(m);
            }
            break;

        }
        case 3: {
            val = sc.nextToken();

            for (int j = st - 1; j <= en - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = new BigInteger("val");

            }
            break;

        }
        case 4: {
            BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("0");
            for (int j = st - 1; j <= en - 1; j++) {
                sum = sum.add(arr[j]);

            }
            sum = sum.mod(m);
            System.out.println(sum);

            break;
        }
    }
    q--;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the exact error report.

Comment: i dont know , it just shows Runtime error(Non zero exit code)